# Invalid types WORD[int] for array subscript

Tags: c++, netburner

Go easy on me, I'm still a newb with C/C++.. I know this has been asked a few times, and I've tried following the solutions given to no avail. This code is for a NetBurner processor, DWORD is 32 bit unsigned, WORD is 16 bit unsigned.

header func.h:

```
class funcs
{
  // ...
  private:
  void myfunc();
  WORD data001;
  DWORD data002[100];
  DWORD data003[100]; 

  // ...
  }
```

I have this function that calls upon that data in my class, funcs.cpp. Assume all variables have been initialized:

```
void funcs::myfunc()
{
  data001++;
  data002[data001] = x;   // random x for this example
  data003[data001] = y;
}
```

My compiler is complaining: "error: invalid types 'DWORD[WORD] for array subscript". I've changed the array subscript type to "int", "unsigned int" and every other type I could think of, and still get the error. I tried the solutions given in previous posts:

```
void funcs::myfunc()
{
  data001++;
  this->data002[data001] = x;   // random x for this example
  this->data003[data001] = y;
}
```

but it was to no avail. I've also tried containing myfunc definition within the class, same error. Any ideas/solutions? I'm stumped. Thanks guys!!

Edit: data types provided in a header file:

```
typedef unsigned char BOOL;
typedef unsigned char BOOLEAN;
typedef unsigned char BYTE; /* Unsigned  8 bit quantity */
typedef signed   short SHORT;/* Signed   16 bit quantity  */
typedef unsigned short WORD; /* Unsigned   16 bit quantity  */
typedef unsigned long DWORD;/* Unsigned 32 bit quantity  */
typedef signed   long LONG; /* Signed   32 bit quantity  */

typedef volatile unsigned char VBOOLEAN;
typedef volatile unsigned char VBYTE;  /* Unsigned  8 bit quantity  */
typedef volatile short VSHORT; /* Signed   16 bit quantity */
typedef volatile unsigned short VWORD;  /* Unsigned   16 bit quantity */
typedef volatile unsigned long VDWORD; /* Unsigned 32 bit quantity   */
typedef volatile signed   long VLONG;  /* Signed   32 bit quantity   */
```

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: It looks to me like for some reason your compiler isn't treating `data002` as an array.

Comment: `DWORD is 32 bit unsigned, WORD is 16` So where exactly are these definitions found? Those are not standard C++ keywords or types, so some header has the actual definition of what these are. I know that `<windows.h>` has them, since Windows API programs use these types.

Comment: Could you post a [complete, minimal test case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the error? You certainly shouldn't get it from the posted code. Either the array index isn't `data001`, or you've declared an array called `data001` instead of (or as well as) the variable you've posted.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie. I posted a clip from the header file.

MikeSeymour I'm not following what you're asking for. I cannot post my original code, not allowed. This is the exact function just names changed. There is no array called  'data001' anywhere in my code.

Comment: I removed the C tag; this is C++, not C.

Comment: The error message "invalid types `DWORD[WORD]` for array subscript" implies that you have an array index operation where the prefix is of type `DWORD` and the index is of type `WORD` -- both integer types. I don't see any such operation in the code fragments you've shown us.

Comment: @JediEngineer: I'm asking for enough code to reproduce the error, as described in the link I gave - a small standalone test case like [this](http://ideone.com/NtpmyG). I put that together from the code you've posted, but it doesn't have the error. If you can post something like that, based on what your real code is doing, which does demonstrate the error, we can see what might be wrong with your real code.

Comment: Thanks @KeithThompson, what I've posted is the slimmed down version of what I have. I have an array of 100 32-bit values, that need to be indexed by a 16 bit value that is incremented every time the function is called. The error I get is coming from the gnu compiler in the NetBurner IDE. I'm not sure why no one here may be seeing this error...

Comment: @MikeSeymour, I'm not sure how much more or less I can provide. What you see is literally what I have, minus 100 other irrelevant functions. I literally just wrote that yesterday. It's not affected anywhere else, so there's nothing left to add.

Comment: In slimming it down, you've removed the code that causes the problem you're asking about.  Can you narrow it down to a small self-contained program that exhibits the problem?

Comment: @KeithThompson, I'll post a screenshot.

Comment: @JediEngineer: But the code you've posted doesn't exhibit the error - something that you left out *was* relevant. If you can post a test case that *does*, then we can figure out why. Otherwise, we can only guess.

Comment: @MikeSeymour - I posted a screenshot from my IDE. I can't fit the top half of the class that says it's under the private heading without cutting something out. Let me know what more I can give. I moved the function to the class header to see if that would help eliminate the error. I can take a screenshot from the class .cpp file if that helps.

Comment: @JediEngineer: No, please post actual code (not a screenshot) which demonstrates the problem. The code I transcribed into my answer would be enough.

Comment: Screenshots are not helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your real code (transcribed from the screenshot) is:

```
DWORD u_data002;
WORD  u_data003;

u_data002[u_data_003] = whatever;
```

which tries to index an integer as if it were an array or pointer.

Presumably, either `u_data002` is supposed to be an array, or you meant to write something other than `u_data002`.

Comment: Mike, data000 to data003 are not arrays. they are variables.

Comment: @JediEngineer: But you try to use `u_data002` as if it were an array. Hence the error.

Comment: I'm an @55 - thanks Mike, I'm sorry, I didn't catch that before.... I'm not sure why I didn't see it before, but man I feel dumb now... thanks again man!!